# Where can I interact with other Esperanto speaking psychologists?

Tags: movado

I got to know one using Amikumu, but I would like to know more Esperantists.

Answer (score 3):

Laŭ mia scio ne ekzistas faka asocio aŭ rondo de psikologoj, sed ekzistas [UMEA](http://umea.fontoj.net/), la fakasocio de medicinistoj, en kiu laŭ ties informoj membras ankaŭ psikoterapiistoj. Do eble vi povus tie aliĝi aŭ peti pri informoj, eble estas pli specialaj dissendolistoj.